# Is Display unique for every window in X11?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I'm a beginner to X11, i created a class just to create,show and destroy the window. In the Constructor i create variables for Window,Display etc, But do i need to create Display for every Window o create or shall i use the same Display for all windows?

```
class Widget
{
public:
Widget();
void createWidget(int x,int y,int w,int h);
void showWidget();
void destroyWidget();

private:
Display *disp;
int screenNumber;
unsigned long white;
unsigned long black;
Window win;
XEvent evt;
long eventMask;
};
```

Comment: Oh please, don't build apps on top of xlib, use GTK or Qt. Qt is a perfect choice, since you are working with C++.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be nothing wrong with xlib :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on where you want to create the window. If it is on the same system - same GPU, then yes, you can use the same Display.

Comment: Not only you can, you actually should use the same Display connection. Most X servers can maintain a only rather low number of connections (between 256 to 1024), to be conservative about this resource.

Answer (score 2):

Use one Display for all Windows in your application.